# how to edit a csv in python and add one row after the 2nd row that will have the same values in all columns except 1

Tags: python, csv

I'm new in Python language and i'm facing a small challenge in which i havent been able to figure it out so far.
I receive a csv file with around 30-40 columns and 5-50 rows with various details in each cell. The 1st row of the csv has the title for each column and by the 2nd row i have item values.
What i want to do is to create a python script which will read the csv file and every time to do the following:
Add a row after the actual 1st item row, (literally after the 2nd row, cause the 1st row is titles), and in that new 3rd row to contain the same information like the above one with one difference only. in the column "item_subtotal" i want to add the value from the column "discount total". 
all the bellow rows should remain as they are, and save this modified csv as a new file with the word "edited" added in the file name.
I could really use some help because so far i've only managed to open the csv file with a python script im developing, but im not able so far to add the contents of the above row to that newly created row and replace that specific value.
Looking forward any help.
Thank you

Here Im attaching the CSV with some values changed for privacy reasons.

order_id,order_number,date,status,shipping_total,shipping_tax_total,fee_total,fee_tax_total,tax_total,discount_total,order_total,refunded_total,order_currency,payment_method,shipping_method,customer_id,billing_first_name,billing_last_name,billing_company,billing_email,billing_phone,billing_address_1,billing_address_2,billing_postcode,billing_city,billing_state,billing_country,shipping_first_name,shipping_last_name,shipping_address_1,shipping_address_2,shipping_postcode,shipping_city,shipping_state,shipping_country,shipping_company,customer_note,item_id,item_product_id,item_name,item_sku,item_quantity,item_subtotal,item_subtotal_tax,item_total,item_total_tax,item_refunded,item_refunded_qty,item_meta,shipping_items,fee_items,tax_items,coupon_items,order_notes,download_permissions_granted,admin_custom_order_field:customer_type_5
15001_TEST_2,,"2017-10-09 18:53:12",processing,0,0.00,0.00,0.00,5.36,7.06,33.60,0.00,EUR,PayoneCw_PayPal,"0,00",0,name,surname,,name.surname@gmail.com,0123456789,"address 1",,41541_TEST,location,,DE,name,surname,address,01245212,14521,location,,DE,,,1328,302,"product title",103,1,35.29,6.71,28.24,5.36,0.00,0,,"id:1329|method_id:free_shipping:3|method_title:0,00|total:0.00",,id:1330|rate_id:1|code:DE-MWST-1|title:MwSt|total:5.36|compound:,"id:1331|code:#getgreengent|amount:7.06|description:Launchcoupon for friends","text string",1,

Comment: post the input file contents and the expected result

Comment: Wall of text, no input data example and no expected output. Downvoted. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Anton,
I've edited my post and added example data. Sorry for my rookie mistake. WIll follow the guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use pandas to manipulate the data from the csv like this:

```
import pandas
import copy
```

Read the csv file into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filename)
```

Make a deepcopy of the first row of data and add the discount total to the item subtotal:

```
new_row = copy.deepcopy(df.loc[1])
new_row['item_subtotal'] += new_row['discount total']
```

Concatenate the first 2 rows with the new row and then everything after that:

```
df = pandas.concat([df.loc[:1], new_row, df.loc[2:]], ignore_index=True)
```

Change the filename and write the out the new csv file:

```
filename = filename.strip('.csv') + 'edited.csv'
df.to_csv(filename)
```

I hope this helps! Pandas is great for cleanly handling massive amounts of data, but may be overkill for what you are trying to do. Then again, maybe not. It would help to see an example data file.

Comment: Thank you MacKenzie,
I'will post tomorrow commenting and my results. 
I havent used Pandas so much, but yes, seems like that i do need to do some more studying and exercises about this topic.

Comment: Hello L. Mackenzie
Thank you very much for your answer and help! Really i wouldnt have been able to write this code for the time cause im not that experienced with pandas, but seems like a fantastic library in which i already study further.
Now, i've tested your code but i get the following error: KeyError: 'the label [1] is not in the [index]'  
Ive edited my post and added the CSV for example purposes. 
When i open the CSV in Excel the csv contents are presented nicely in rows, but when i open it with Notepad++ there are no rows. 
So how would that value be changed now?
Thank you again

Comment: Notepad++ treats the csv file as simply a text file, but Excel treats it as a csv (comma separated values) and so it separates the values into different columns. That is why it appears different in Excel vs. Notepad++. As for the KeyError you are getting, it is difficult to debug without the full Traceback and the code you ran with the csv file you used.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to turn that .csv into something that is a little easier to work with. Fortunately, python has the 'csv' module which makes it easy to turn your .csv file into a much nicer list of lists. The below will give you a way to both turn your .csv into a list of lists and turn the modified data back into a .csv file.

```
import csv
import copy

def csv2list(ifile):
    """
    ifile = the path of the csv to be converted into a list of lists
    """
    f = open(ifile,'rb')
    olist=[]
    c = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
    for line in c:
        olist.append(line) #and update the outer array
    f.close
    return olist

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def list2csv(ilist,ofile):
    """
    ilist =  the list of lists to be converted
    ofile = the output path for your csv file
    """
    with open(ofile, 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        [csvwriter.writerow(x) for x in ilist]
```

Now, you can simply copy list[1] and change the appropriate element to reflect your summed value using:

```
listTemp = copy.deepcopy(ilist[1])
listTemp[n] = listTemp[n] + listTemp[n-x]

ilist.insert(2,listTemp)
```

As for how to change the file name, just use:

```
import os

newFileName = os.path.splitext(oldFileName)[0] + "edited" + os.path.splitext(oldFileName)[1]
```

Hopefully this will help you out!

Comment: Hello Keith,
I've followed your suggestion and although it prints out in the console the list, i get the following error: TypeError: descriptor 'insert' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'
I've tried changing that integer to other values but still havent figured out how to correctly do it. 
Thank you very much for your assistance. 
Hope soon, i will also be able to assist others too!

Comment: something more,
if i dont add:  
def listTemp(list):   
before the   
listTemp = list[1]
etc..
i get the error: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: To clarify, I'm using Python 2.7... I'm able to get that code working on a random test .csv file. I'm not actually using 'list' as a variable name of course. Also, you will need to make an actual copy of 'ilist[1]' by using 'import copy' and using 'listTemp = copy.deepcopy(ilist[1])' instead of what's there